# org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument retrieve only 1 page from my PDF file

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying ro read PDF file with Java and pdfbox, but it returns only 1 page (first). What could be an issue? please help.

here is my code:

```
public static PDDocument openPDFfile(String path) {

        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(path);
            BufferedInputStream file = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            document = PDDocument.load(file);
                        System.out.println(document.getNumberOfPages());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("The PDF file doesnt exist");
        }
        return document;
    }
```

console output:
1

I tried w/o BufferedInputStream and URL, the same result.

```
public static PDDocument openPDFfile(String path) {

        PDDocument document = null;
        try {           
            document = PDDocument.load(new File("pdf.pdf"));
                        System.out.println(document.getNumberOfPages());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("The PDF file doesnt exist");
        }
        return document;
    }
```

I guess it could be related to the file format, but I cant found out it, or maybe the way my security software blocks a certain java tasks. The file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/107NZDAXOALVmJoOFEHAuLMIgSWSS1CCd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The second code should be ok I have tested with pdfbox 2.0.1. PDDocument.load(new File("pdf.pdf")); My result is 98 pages.

Comment: Most likely your pdf simply has only 1 page. You may have a PDF with an xfa Form definition. Such pdfs often contain just one pdf page plus the form which may be displayed as many pages.

Comment: @WingKuiTsoi The current PDFBox version is 2.0.28.

Comment: Please share your PDF (upload to sharehoster).

Comment: I randomly searched sample pdf for you which is from Arfica University. 2.0.28 version can make it. https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr

Here is the file. Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestions and help! 

https://na4520.sharefile.com/d-sb6cff0a54af942f78a07404c3ba1a18e

Comment: @mkl how can I check if my PDF is that format that you described? Here is the link to my file: https://na4520.sharefile.com/d-sb6cff0a54af942f78a07404c3ba1a18e
If you could please tell me what is wrong with this file and give me some suggestions on how I can read all the pages, I would very much appreciate it! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your link requires login data which I don't have.

Comment: @mkl Most of the sharing portals require you to have an account with them. it is free, you can sign in with your Gmail.

Comment: @Vladek721 None of us would sign up, even if it's free. Use one that doesn't require signup. Filedropper or google drive.

Comment: *"Most of the sharing portals require you to have an account with them."* - Not in my experience, at least not for the downloader if the uploader selects it so. (BTW, another no-go would be excessive advertisements.)

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr Thank you for providing other options. I used Gdrive this time. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/107NZDAXOALVmJoOFEHAuLMIgSWSS1CCd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @mkl I hope this link will work for you as well. Sorry for the inconvenience with the previous link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/107NZDAXOALVmJoOFEHAuLMIgSWSS1CCd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @KJ Could you please give me a few examples of a "bad filename or an access rights problem"? I thought since I could access the PDF file and my code read at least one, first page, that the file is accessible to the system, I could open it manually as the same user that my code use. But maybe I am wrong... Also, I don't understand what could be wrong with the name, if, again, the file opens with the code and reads at least, one page. Please point me in the right direction if you could, thank you in advance!

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue, in my test `document.getNumberOfPages()` returns 14 for your file. Which PDFBox version do you use? I tested with the current PDFBox 2 version 2.0.28.

Answer (score 1):

I faced an issue where I was mistakenly opening a different PDF file with a similar name and identical first page. It took me a while to identify the problem, but I'm grateful for everyone who responded and attempted to assist me. I truly appreciate your help! This experience served as a reminder to always debug code step by step and pay close attention to details in order to avoid similar issues. Best of luck to you all!

Comment: I'm happy that you got your problem fixed and yes these mistakes have happened to all of use, but IMHO this is the type of question that should just be removed, maybe after a delay of 1 day or 2. (I won't flag it)